# Writing string to a file on a new line every time in Python

Tags: python, newline

I have a **loop**, which have to write text on a new line **every time**. Here`s the code in Python:

```
    for j in b:
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(j))
        data = json.dumps(data)
        data = json.loads(data)
        from_id = data['from_id']
        text = data['text']
        if (os.path.exists(f'{user_id}.txt')):
            with open(f'{user_id}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write(f'{from_id}: {text}\n')
```

I tried to use *\n* at the end, but it doesnt work for me.
As **result** it just writes **the last line** of the loop`s text.

**Text:**

```
Abcdefg
Gkfdjawsfd
fasfjk
```

**Result:**

```
fasfjk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The write mode `w` writes from the beginning of the file.

When the code is not looped, you just want to append, just append mode `a`, it would look like :

```
with open(f'{user_id}.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(f'{from_id}: {text}\n')
```

But here you have a loop and the file isn't dependent of the loop (`user_id` is not defined in the loop), so you can just open the file outside the loop once

```py
with open(f'{user_id}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for data in b:
        from_id = data['from_id']
        text = data['text']
        file.write(f'{from_id}: {text}\n')
```

Also the dumps/loads part seems useless, I removed it